# Reducing power usage on windows server

Tags: hp-proliant, windows-server-2019, electrical-power

I have a Proliant Microserver Gen8 running windows server 2019 with a Xeon E3 1260L, one SSD for OS, and two 3TB 5400 RPM disks for storage (software raid).

The server acts as a NAS and has a few small web apis on it. For the absolute majority of the day this server is sitting idle with no queries at all (I'd wager it sees less than 2 hours usage per 24 hours).

So, as a fun experiment I want to reduce the power usage of this machine while it is in idle state to the lowest possible while still maintaining system stability. It is completly fine that it takes time to answer initial queries.

I have experimented with reducing minimum processor and maximum processor state, and while idle the server now uses 35 watts (measured with plug between server and socket). When it's in use it uses about 65 watts.

I reckon thats pretty good, but is there anything else I can do that would reduce Idle power usage?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check in the BIOS to make sure powersaving is enabled, but your option are limited as the system will always try to run everything to make sure no hardware problem can arise, like the fan and all the material in the box (iLO, etc..)

See the Minimum Power Usager's setting there;

[image]

If you want an "green" or powersaving NAS, I recommand build-in system that are done for that purpose. A HP, or Dell/IBM would always have high power usage vs other small NAS appliance.

Comment: Yeah I checked that, its on OS control right now, and that gives about +- 1 Watt the same usage in idle as minimum power usage.

Comment: I guessed there would not be much more to be done but was hoping :)